# How users can fill up form after login with facebook in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal

I am developing a drupal website. When user clicks on signup link, he has the option  of login with facebook or twitter, after the user is logged in, one form should come in popup to fill other details like address, phone number etc.
How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve functionality to create a form and set it up after login in Drupal 7.

You can create form either using Webform (Setup rules using [Webform Rules]) or CCK module.
Then use [RULES](https://drupal.org/project/rules) module for redirection after login.

The following link might be helpful, if you want to achieve this by writing hook.
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7